# How to add a static library permanently to the Ubuntu system?

Tags: c++, compilation, header, static-libraries

Hi everybody I recently created a C++ project in which I put my code into *header.h* and *header.cpp* files and successfully create a static library called *header.a*. Now I put my *header.h* file into /usr/local/include position of my system and *header.a* into /usr/local/lib in order to "install" my library into the machine. Now, if I want to use this library, I have to do the following steps:

1. Suppose I am using a *main.cpp* program, I include this line at the top of the program:

```
include <header.h>
```

2. Then, I compile with this command:

```
g++ main.cpp /usr/local/lib/header.a
```

And all it's ok. But I want to find a way to "store" permanently the *header.a* library into the system in order to use it like a normal standard C++ header, simplifing the compilation in this way:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

Is there a way to do this? Many thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, and no system library will be linked automatically without being told to do so.

You can however add the path `/usr/local/lib` to the default paths for the linker to look for libraries (IIRC it's not in there by default for Ubuntu), which means you only need to add the `-l` (lower-case L) option to link with the library.

But do note that the library should be having a `lib` prefix. Like in `libheader.a`.

Then link with `-lheader`:

```
g++ main.cpp -lheader
```

---

There also the `-L` option to add a path to the list of paths that the linker searches, if you have other non-standard paths, of if you can't edit the system configuration to use `/usr/local/lib`:

```
g++ main.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lheader
```

The library file still needs the `lib` prefix.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer has been very useful!